# Settings.settings table is not shown

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

I'm playing around with settings, in my WPF App, under VS2019.
Normally I've learned that doubleclicking Settings.settings in the solution explorer shoud rise a table, to define the settings.
On my VS only a xml-style file is shown but I don't find any hints in the internet, on how to style the settings, without this nice table.

Can please someone help me?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="uri:settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)">
  <Profiles>
    <Profile Name="(Default)" />
  </Profiles>
  <Settings />
</SettingsFile>
```

It would be enough to know the needed nodes in that xml-document.

Answer (score 0):

Within your project right-click your `.settings`-file and select `Open With...`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This will open a menu where you can choose a default editor for your file:

[image]

The `Settings Designer` is probably what you will want to set as default by selecting it and pressing the `Set as Default`-button. Finally hit `OK` to apply the settings.

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, this seems to be the problem. Settings Designer isn't in the list. Couldn't find the program file of it :(

Comment: Well maybe there is something wrong with your vs-installation.. If you don't have the latest version, probably try updating it. Probably try another WPF-project to see if the you will face the same problem (in case that something is wrong with your project) ... Hard to guess whats wrong without further information.